# NPE, Each time I try to delete the first visible item in ListView

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, android-listview

I need help figuring out why I get Null pointer exception each time I try to delete the first item in my listView (which is visible). Deleting every other item works fine without any error but the first item keeps failing.

here is the code:

```
private void deleteCurrentItem() {
        ContextualUndoView contextualUndoView = (ContextualUndoView) mDismissView;
        int position = getAbsListView().getPositionForView(contextualUndoView);


        mDeleteItemCallback.deleteItem(position);

    }
```

Detailed code: http://paste.org/66633

error log:

```
08-10 19:09:22.107: E/AndroidRuntime(973): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-10 19:09:22.107: E/AndroidRuntime(973): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-10 19:09:22.107: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at android.widget.AdapterView.getPositionForView(AdapterView.java:597)
08-10 19:09:22.107: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at com.haarman.listviewanimations.itemmanipulation.contextualundo.ContextualUndoAdapter$RemoveViewAnimatorListenerAdapter.deleteCurrentItem(ContextualUndoAdapter.java:205)
08-10 19:09:22.107: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at com.haarman.listviewanimations.itemmanipulation.contextualundo.ContextualUndoAdapter$RemoveViewAnimatorListenerAdapter.onAnimationEnd(ContextualUndoAdapter.java:193)
08-10 19:09:22.107: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at com.nineoldandroids.animation.ValueAnimator.endAnimation(ValueAnimator.java:1034)
08-10 19:09:22.107: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at com.nineoldandroids.animation.ValueAnimator.cancel(ValueAnimator.java:968)
08-10 19:09:22.107: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at com.haarman.listviewanimations.itemmanipulation.contextualundo.ContextualUndoAdapter$RecycleViewListener.onMovedToScrapHeap(ContextualUndoAdapter.java:276)
08-10 19:09:22.107: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at android.widget.AbsListView$RecycleBin.addScrapView(AbsListView.java:6449)
08-10 19:09:22.107: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1256)
```

Answer (score 0):

this line:

```
ContextualUndoView contextualUndoView = (ContextualUndoView) mDismissView;
```

declares your view, but does not instantiate it (so it is `null` still).

in the next line

```
int position = getAbsListView().getPositionForView(contextualUndoView);
```

You try to use your view but it is still null so you get a null pointer.

Comment: The view `mDismissView` was instantiated earlier in the class. you can refer to the full code [Here](http://pastebin.com/v0Bwb8pA) to see where it was instantiated.  also keep in mind this error only occurs at the first item on the listView.